# How do I get two different counts from a table in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to have my select query pull the count of items that exist in both tables in one column, and the count of the items that only exist in one table.  These two queries give me the data I need, but would like it come from one query. Thanks in advance.

```sql
select 
d.description, 
count(pd.item_id) 
from productdetails pd 
join inventory i on i.itemnum=pd.item_id 
inner join departments d on d.dept_id=i.dept_id 
where i.last_sold is not null and i.in_stock !=0 and len(i.itemnum) >4 and d.DEPT_ID NOT IN ('1010','1010c','1010cc','1010h','1010h','1011','1012','1013','1014','1015','1016','1017','1018','1015p','1015d','1015s','1015u','1251','1401','2000') 
group by d.description

select d.description, 
count(pd.item_id) 
from productdetails pd 
join inventory i on i.itemnum=pd.item_id 
inner join departments d on d.dept_id=i.dept_id 
group by d.description
```

Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that. I made some changes to original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a SUM and an IIF statements  to achive your goal :

```
select  d.description, 
        count(pd.item_id),
        SUM(IIF(i.last_sold is not null and i.in_stock !=0 and len(i.itemnum) >4 and d.DEPT_ID NOT IN ('1010','1010c','1010cc','1010h','1010h','1011','1012','1013','1014','1015','1016','1017','1018','1015p','1015d','1015s','1015u','1251','1401','2000'), 1, 0))
from productdetails pd 
join inventory i on i.itemnum=pd.item_id 
inner join departments d on d.dept_id=i.dept_id 
group by d.description
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I get 'Incorrect syntax near 'IIF' when trying to run it.

Comment: just found the error, a comma was missing

Comment: Yes, I found it as well, this works perfectly, thank you!